# How to use inner join tables in the DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to implement inner join data on DRF. I have two model classes one is `user` and  `client`. When I am adding a client that time I am selecting a list of users which is handled by that client. Now when I am fetching the list of users from the API then I need the client name as well in that API. My modal classes are:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    identifier = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, serialize=False, verbose_name='identifer')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=user_image_file_path)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main_contact = models.ForeignKey(
        'User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="main_contact",
        null=True
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        related_name="users"
    )
```

views.py

```
class GetAllUserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, jwtPermissions.IsSSOAdminOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    pagination_class = PostLimitOffsetPagination
    serializer_class = GetAllUserSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class GetAllUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = '__all__'
```

Any suggestions is of great help!

Answer (score 1):

since you are using DRF, one simple way is to rely on the DRF built-in functionality:

For clarity, assuming this is your `models.py`

```py
class User(models.Model):
    identifier = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, serialize=False, verbose_name='identifer')
  

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main_contact = models.ForeignKey(
        'User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="main_contact",
        null=True
    )
```

Then

1. create a `ModelSerializer` for `Client`

```py
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
```

2. change your `UserSerializer` as follows:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    clients = ClientSerializer(many=True, source='main_contact')
    queryset = User.objects.prefetch_related('main_contact').all()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

this way, you should be able to get all users and their clients as well.

reference:

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related